# building DOCKERFILE in vs code doesnt work with private registries

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, dockerfile, docker-registry

in vscode using the docker extension i right click and 'build image...'. the docker file contains FROM privateRegistry.com:port/image as the first line. this gives the error

```
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for privateRegistry.com:port/image                                                                                                         0.1s 
------
 > [internal] load metadata for privateRegistry.com:port/image:
------
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head "privateRegistry.com:port/v2/image/manifests/3.9.4": http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client
```

but when i run docker info i can see the registry in insecure registries and i can pull and run docker images outside of vscode. is there any extra settings to get this to worj with vs code ? many thanks

Comment: Even adding the registry into vs code doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the insecure registry needed http:// before the address - adding this fixed the problem and now works within vs code